# Cut the list in Java

Tags: java, list

I created a class `Data` in Java. This is a source code of this simple help class:

```
class Data {

    private Integer x;
    private Integer y;

    Data(Integer x, Integer y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    protected Integer get_x() {
        return x;
    }

    protected Integer get_y() {
        return y;
    }

}
```

After that I use my class `Data` to create some `List<Data> container`. I add the elements in my `container` with the help of the `add` methods and sort my List. Finally I print out the output:

```
for(Data data : container){
    System.out.println("Print x: " + data.get_x() + ", Print y: " + data.get_y()); 
}
```

The possible output could be:

```
Print x: 1, Print y: 3
Print x: 1, Print y: 5
Print x: 1, Print y: 2
Print x: 1, Print y: 4
Print x: 1, Print y: 5
Print x: 1, Print y: 2
Print x: 1, Print y: 6
Print x: 1, Print y: 7
Print x: 2, Print y: 3
Print x: 2, Print y: 5
Print x: 2, Print y: 2
Print x: 2, Print y: 4
Print x: 2, Print y: 5
Print x: 2, Print y: 2
Print x: 2, Print y: 6
Print x: 2, Print y: 7
...
```

The length of every unique `x`-part could be variable, also I don't need to know, how many different values of `x` I have in my List. Now my question is: is it possible to create another List (or modify this one), which have only limited and fixed number of **top** `x` values in the list and remove the other? For example I want only 3 values for every x value. The output should be like:

```
Print x: 1, Print y: 3
Print x: 1, Print y: 5
Print x: 1, Print y: 2
Print x: 2, Print y: 3
Print x: 2, Print y: 5
Print x: 2, Print y: 2
```

Comment: Any 3 values? Or specific ones?

Comment: specific top values, from top part of every x

Comment: you could create a `Map<Integer,List<Data>>`. Here you could check the size of `map.get(1)`, where `1` would be your x value. If this value is less then `4` then you could add elements, otherwise not. If you would want to get a full `List` of all elements then you could just create one `List` out of all aviable `Lists`.

Comment: ok, thanks, will try it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution is to store a `List<Data>` for each `x` value you have in a `Map<Integer, List<Data>>`.

```
Map<Integer, List<Data>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Data data : container) {
    List<Data> value = map.get(data.get_x());
    if (value == null) {
        map.put(data.get_x(), new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(data)));
    } else if (value.size() < 3) {
        value.add(data);
    }
}
```

In this code, we loop over all the data and retrieve the current list for the current `x` data. If it is null, it means there is currently no value so we add a new list containing only the current data (wrapping `Arrays.asList` into a new `ArrayList` because it returns a fixed-size list). Else, and if the list has less than 3 elements then we add the current one.

This will keep only the first 3 elements for each `x` value.

---

Using Java 8, this loop can be simplified a little:

```
Map<Integer, List<Data>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Data data : container) {
    List<Data> list = map.computeIfAbsent(data.get_x(), k -> new ArrayList<Data>());
    if (list.size() < 3) {
        list.add(data);
    }
}
```

---

If you want to have a `List` of all the values (instead of a `Map`), there is a simpler way (using Java 8): keep a `Map<Integer, Integer>` mapping each `x` value with the number of times it appears:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
List<Data> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
for (Data data : container) {
    int count = map.merge(data.get_x(), 1, Integer::sum);
    if (count < 3) {
        filtered.add(data);
    }
}
```

The `filtered` list will have the wanted results. In this code `map.merge` inserts 1 if there was no mapping or else add 1 to the previous mapping.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, I know Java 8 syntax and use it in my code.